# Using a pre-defined variable in a range of cells (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use a variable to define a portion of a range of cells in VBA. In the code below, I pre-defined the `counter` and would like that to be the row number of the end portion of the range.

```
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "$A$2:$A&counter"
```

For example, if the counter were 5, the range would be $A$2:$A$5. But the counter changes. This doesn't compile and I'm stuck. Can anyone help?

Comment: ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "$A$2:$A$" & counter

Answer (score 3):

You need to concatenate strings, which in VBA is done with `&` operator.

[How to concatenate strings in VBA](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/concat2.php)

So, you need to use:

```
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "$A$2:$A" & counter
```